# Magnets side by side, same polarity, attraction side-ways, repulsion along diagonal?

Tags: electromagnetism

Here with two cylinder magnets side by side under a ferrocell you can see that there is repulsion along the diagonal, attraction side ways since magnets oriented in opposite polarity, but repulsion across diameter between like poles. Is there a vector of repulsion, like the ferrocell shows?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seen some of these images in other questions recently - think they got closed... might have a look in a bit.

Comment: To stick to the topic, what is your opinion on if the magnetic field pattern shows a vector of repulsion along the diagonal?